# Show that a set of vectors is linearly dependent or linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, independence

I'm having a bit of trouble with this problem. I know what linear dependence implies, but I'm not exactly sure how to apply it to this problem to investigate the second set given to us.

Suppose that S = {v1, v2, v3} is a linearly independent set of three vectors
from C^347. Is the set T = {2v1 + v2 − v3, 2v1 + 3v2 + v3, v1 − v2 + 2v3} linearly dependent or linearly independent?

Comment: There are a few ways to do this. One 'mechanical' way is to use matrix techniques like gaussian elimination. The more theoretical approach would be to simply apply the definition: a set $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n$ of vectors is linearly independent if and only if $\sum_{i=1}^nc_ix_i=0$ implies $c_1=c_2=\dots=c_n=0$.

Answer (score 0):

If $\mathbf S$ is the set=matrix of independent column vectors and 
$$
\mathbf{T} = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   2 & 1 & { - 1}  \\
   2 & 3 & 1  \\
   1 & { - 1} & 2  \\
 \end{array} } \right)\;\,\mathbf{S} = \mathbf{A}\;\mathbf{S}
$$
and $\mathbf T$ is also a matrix of independent vectors, then it shall be possible
to invert this relation
$$
\mathbf{S} = \mathbf{A}^{\, - \,\mathbf{1}} \;\mathbf{T}
$$
i.e. the matrix of the coefficients shall be invertible, i.e. its determinant shall be non null.
Viceversa if the determinant of $\mathbf{A} $ is not null, it is not possible to get a null vector
by multiplying the matrix by a non-null vector.

Comment: Thank you for the response! But we're supposed to achieve this problem using only what we know about linear dependence relationships and cannot use anything regarding invertability and determinants quite yet. Is there a way you think this could be accomplished otherwise?

Comment: @Jason: ok, but first of all , what is the meaning of "C^347"?